# Кроссплатформенный способ получения информации о системе

Tags: c++, железо, ос, кроссплатформенность

Дoбрый вeчep!

Задача:

Получить следующую информацию: (по мере важности)

1. Количество ядер процессора
2. Количество доступной RAM памяти
3. Количество доступной HDD памяти
4. Вендор процессора и максимальная доступная частота
5. Вендор и версия ОС
6. Разрядность

Важное условие - код должен выполняться на ЛЮБОЙ ОС!!!

И тут я не знаю, что делать...

**Самое главное - первые два пункта**

Можете помочь или скинуть ссылку с гайдом?

Comment: 1. {boost,std}::thread::hardware_concurrency()

Comment: 4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666093/cpuid-implementations-in-c

Comment: А Вам надо только чтобы только на x86 архитектуре работало, или на ARM и прочих архитектурах тоже?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 на x64